# How to finish multiple activities on logout android

Tags: android, android-activity

In my app i am starting activities one after the another and not finishing any activity before calling another. But when user presses logout button then i want to finish all the activities from the stack and start login activity.

> Activity Login(finish & call) --> Activity B --> Activity C-->
>   Activity D --> Logout 
>   -->Acitivity Login.

If user presses back key on login activity then he returns to Activity C in my case... but i want to avoid that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you should do is call `Login` activity, and clear all activities above it in the stack.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will flag it to create a new login activity, not just resume the previous one. And clear all activities above it. (B, C, D).

Comment: for me, it works when I replace FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP by FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will going to help, but you could try to add to your manifest's declared activities (B, C, D) the following tag:

`android:noHistory='true'`

> the activity should be removed from the activity stack and finished
>   (its finish() method called) when the user navigates away from it and
>   it's no longer visible on screen

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist).

Comment: thanks @yugidroid but i actually dont want to finish my previous activity bcoz it has downloaded data from server if my finish and come back it will to it again ... so i wanted to finish all previous activity only on logout..... anyhow the solution of Doomskinght worked for me